# Accessing dvips features of xypic via pdflatex

Tags: xy-pic

I read from the `xypic` reference manual that extra graphics features are accessible using `dvips` to compile, even though it still works in most cases with `pdflatex`. On the PSTricks website are listed several methods to compile a document with `pstricks` code using `pdflatex`.

Are there similar ways to compile a document with `xypic` code using `pdflatex` while still having access to `dvips` specials? Please list the various methods and compare them where applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
...
\begin{postscript}
... your xy stuff
\end{postscript}
...
```

and then as usual `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>`

Comment: `auto-pst-pdf` runs a command from the shell to convert Postscript to PDF.  Taco Hoekwater is developing a Postscript interpreter in Lua, [Escrito](http://escrito.luatex.org/), which will allow this all to be done internally in Luatex.

Comment: Escrito is a project and a long standing one ... no more no less

Comment: Herbert: Development has stalled, but Taco did recently reiterate his commitment to it, and he has an excellent track record with projects.

Comment: @Charles: if it may ever be finished I spent you a sixpack of bear. And "finished" means, that it works :-) and not only for PS Level 1 which is really simple to realize

Comment: You're thinking about the trouble that the Ghostscript writers had?  I guess you are probably right.

Answer (score 4):

Most of what is possible with `\xyoption{ps}` (and dvi+dvips) is possible also via `\xyoption{pdf}` and pdflatex (actually, the manual of xypdf states that something is done better with xypdf than with xyps).